# Hold down button unity3d

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build a button that changes the game speed when it is being pressed and changes it back when it stops being pressed.

To make this I wrote this functions:

```
public void OnPointerDown()
        {
            mouseDown = true;
            Background1.sprite = on;
            Time.timeScale = 2;
        }

public void OnPointerUp()
        {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            mouseDown = false;
            Background1.sprite = off;
        }
```

They are already connected to the button. When the button is pressed the game speed changes, but never changes back (it should happen when I stop holding the button).

Know how to fix this?

Comment: You code is working as expected on my side Put `Debug.Log` in your `OnPointerUp` function and see if that is being called.

Comment: In your Update() you may want to print Debug.Log(Time.timeScale); ensure it's staying at those values desired and not resettting.